# How do I scroll down vertically in a specific div in a web page

Tags: java, javascript, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have searched all the forums but I didn't get a correct answer for my issue. My web page to test has a link hidden below, and I am trying to find it manually by searching for it with xpath or the ID attribute of the element, but I am not able to find it when I am running the web driver script. Even when it is not giving any error on that element, I am getting an error on next command/line.

I found below code from the forums, which is scrolling whole page. I don't want this, I want to scroll down vertically in a specific div area as in screen shot.

```
JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsx.executeScript("ctl00_Menu1_scrollDiv.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
div id for this is "ctl00_Menu1_scrollDiv"
Element id: ctl00_Menu1_DlMenu_ctl09_LnkMenuname
```

Please help me on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: is keeping a frame inside the div an option ??

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Inside div they have used a table. please find the attached new screen shot Code.jpg

Comment: how does the table creates a prob ?? keep the iframe inside div , and the table inside iframe

Comment: Why in the world would you use an iframe? Bad advice there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this works for you.

```
var s = $('#ctl00_Menu1_scrollDiv').scrollTop();
```

This will give the current value of the scroll in the div.Use this only if you want to scroll inside a div to a certain point dynamically. Otherwise you can hardcode the scrollTop value inside animate()

Using the current value of your scroll you can parameterize the given below scrollTop parameter

```
$("#ctl00_Menu1_scrollDiv").animate({ scrollTop: "100px" }); // Here 100 px is just an example
```

I had used this to scroll a large div programmatically in my webdriver framework. Also, this will work if your AUT has jQuery loaded in the browser.

In Java:

```
JavascriptExecutor js;
js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("$(\"#ctl00_Menu1_scrollDiv\").animate({ scrollTop: \"100px\" })");
```

Comment: Are you asking for native webdriver code (In java) to perform scroll? I fear it's not possible. You will HAVE to use JavascriptExecutor.

Comment: @UmamaheshwarThota Please consider accepting the answer if any of them help.

Comment: Sure Abhijeet Vaikar.

Comment: Thanks Abhijeet Vaikar for your answer. i was asking you the same code you have given second time in Java. It worked for me. Thanks again.                                                   JavascriptExecutor js;
js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("$(\"#ctl00_Menu1_scrollDiv\").animate({ scrollTop: \"100px\" })");

Answer (score 3):

This is umendra tomar , I have found very simple solution for this, please use the below code for scroll a specific div in html using selenium .

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('scrollCustom').scrollTop= 450");

scrollCustom =  this is the ID of your div which you want to scroll.
document.getElementById =  this is use in javascript to locate a webelement.
```

Don't worry we can use this in java using `javascriptExecutor`

Answer (score 0):

First you should not just reference an element by the id. You should set scrollTop to scroll it to a position.

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_Menu1_scrollDiv").scrollTop(250);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can you please give code in java, how to use this above statement.

Answer (score 0):

Non-JQuery solution based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1592609/4163398).

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
    "arguments[0].scrollTop=arguments[1].offsetTop",
    divWithScrollbarElement,
    elementToScrollTo);
```

where `divWithScrollbarElement` is the div element which you are looking to scroll, and `elementToScrollTo` is the child element which you want to make viewable (which in my case was actually the parent of the element which I was initially trying to view). If `elementToScrollTo` is not actually in the DOM yet, you may need to use the script once to scroll down as far as possible, and then again once more elements have loaded.