# How to scroll in div with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scroll in table on the page.
I had read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635798/how-do-i-scroll-down-vertically-in-a-specific-div-in-a-web-page). But it didn't works for me. [This is page were table presented](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList). How can i select it with webdriver and scroll to the bottom of it? Content in table is loadable. I need this to count how many items is in the table now. Maybe exists some other hint to make it easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scroll using JavaScript:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsExec.executeScript("document.querySelector('#gwt-debug-contentPanel > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > div.GNHGC04CJJ').scrollTop = 500");
```

But to find out the number there's an easier way:

```
WebElement number = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#gwt-debug-contentPanel > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > div.gwt-HTML"));
String range = number.getText();
```

Then parse the higher number to an integer.