# How to scroll down within a DIV and not in the whole Page via Selenium [JAVA]

Tags: java, selenium

How to scroll down within a DIV and not in the whole Page via Selenium JAVA

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635798/how-do-i-scroll-down-vertically-in-a-specific-div-in-a-web-page) might help you.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189182/how-to-scroll-a-specific-div-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Comment: @akshaygoyal Can you consider showing us your work please? Thanks

Comment: Please put some effort  first to find the solution of your problem. still not getting then explain the specific problem and add your question with proper description and effort you did

Answer (score 3):

Use `JavascriptExecutor`

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

But you need to explore various conditions under executeScript method.

Or,

You can use Action class if you require to move other element, `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions`

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.perform();
```

Comment: This code scroll down to the particular element. Here, OP wants to scroll within an element.