# How to scroll to an ID inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html

The code contains a `div` which should scroll to a special `id` inside that. I have tried this code, but it does not scroll at all and there is no error being thrown as well.

```js
var divToHighlight = document.getElementById(mID);
divToHighlight.style.backgroundColor ="#F5F0C9";
var topPos = divToHighlight.offsetTop; 
document.getElementById("My-Div").scrollTop = topPos;
```

I have also checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635706/how-to-scroll-to-an-element-inside-a-div)  but I can't figure out why my code does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to scroll the parent element, not your div.  Something like this would work.

```
var divToHighlight = document.getElementById(mID);
divToHighlight.style.backgroundColor ="#F5F0C9";
var topPos = divToHighlight.offsetTop;  
divToHighlight.parentElement.scrollTop = topPos;
```

See it working here:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/L6bvwg20/1/

Hope that helps!

Comment: I want to scroll inside the div. the mID is an element inside the Div which should come to the top of the Div. Actually I have no problem when my data was inside the body, but I had to put it inside a scrolling Div. But this one does not work now.

Comment: @adonis I updated the answer to scroll the parent div, instead of the body.

Comment: Thanx Adam. your code helped me pretty much. the problem was that my Div had a heigth of 500. I had to reduce it from topPos to stay at correct position. Now its working :)