# Report viewer for web page: automatically scroll the page when View Report button is clicked?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

Using the viewer control for display of **SQL Reporting Services reports** on a web page (Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms), can we **automatically scroll** the report below *parameter list* when the View Report button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not built into th report viewer. If you want to take the task yourself...The report will be rendered inside of a `IFrame` in the html returned to the client. I can't remember the name of the frame, however, I think it changes based on if you are using `DeviceSettings.RenderAsFragment`. Since you are not getting the report through the `ReportExecution` api then you can safely assume the report content will always be rendered in the same DIV. I think it is named something like --> `<div = "OData">` or something. You will have to find the frame and then use the answer below to apply your scroll logic.

[How to scroll to an element inside a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635706/how-to-scroll-to-an-element-inside-a-div)