# Chrome keeps auto scrolling my mvc view to top

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am facing an issue in my MVC project that when I run it in Chrome, Chrome keeps auto scrolling it to top. I need to disable it or handle it to ot scroll. The chrome version I am using is 70.0.3538.110.

Here is the piece of code I am using to forcefully scroll to bottom:

```
domElement.scrollTop = domElement.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Does that code work ? Have you tried *window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);* ?

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj It does when I implement in a  new implemented project but not working in my case for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any web worker running which tampers scrolling? If yes then try disabling them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to scroll to the bottom of the dom element, not just to the top of it.

```
domElement.scrollTop = domElement.scrollHeight + domElement.offsetTop;
```

Comment: Alrite. While I try it out. Could you give a little bit detail as to why that needs to be done, and what specific in chrome is making it do that, as I am not facing this issue in any other browser.

Comment: You will find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635706/how-to-scroll-to-an-element-inside-a-div)