# How do I scroll a list created with Labels?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to programmatically scroll a list made from `label`s, but I don't know how to do that.

I'd like to be able to set the 1000 label at the top of the list. How can I do that?

```css
.fuel_select {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 60px;
  /* width of list */
  /* cursor: pointer; */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="fuel_select" style="height:150px; width:50px;">
        <label data-fuel_moment="0.00">0</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="298.16">100</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="591.18">200</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="879.08">300</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="1165.42">400</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="1448.40">500</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="1732.53">600</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="2014.80">700</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="2298.84">800</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="2581.92">900</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="2866.30">1000</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="3150.18">1100</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="3434.52">1200</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="3718.52">1300</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="4003.23">1400</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="4287.76">1500</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="4572.24">1600</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="4856.56">1700</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="5141.16">1800</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="5425.64">1900</label>
        <label data-fuel_moment="5709.90">2000</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635706/how-to-scroll-to-an-element-inside-a-div

Comment: That did help me! Thank you very much!