# How to make d-flex items scrollable and focusable in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I would like to ask about some help. I have Gallery with buttons and images. It just work fine but have some issues...

1. I don't know how I should make bar with images bellow selected images scrollable to see all images from start to end.
2. This bar should after every button click focus current image in bottom bar.

That means if I focus f.e 5th image it should move scrollbar to position to be able to see that image on bottom.

How can I achieve that please? Thx for help.

My sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-dewdney-rm4pb?file=/src/App.js

// For some reason i have to open it in anonym. window mode, otherside it won't load view

Preveiw:
[image]

I tried put class overflow-auto on bar with image previews but it wasn't good

Comment: I put my sandbox list on my post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635706/how-to-scroll-to-an-element-inside-a-div

Can you please try this solution? And tell us if it works.

Comment: Yes it helps a lot. Thx

Comment: Please tell us if it works for you, so we can provide the answer and leave it here.