# How can I make a div slowly slide out (with CSS' transition property) when a specific button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the hint-bubble div slowly slide out (with 'transition: 0.5s') whenever hint-btn is clicked. I managed to make it work so that the hint-bubble shows up when the button is clicked, but it shows up instantly, I can't figure out how to slow down the transition.

HTML:

```
<body>
            <div class="hints">
                <p>Need help?</p>
                <br>
                <p>Click button below to get some hints!<p>
                <button class="hint-btn">Hints</button>
            </div>
            <div class="hint-bubble">I would like this div to slide out when "Hints" button is clicked</div>
        </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.hints {
    right: 28rem;
    bottom: 33.4rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #707070;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px black;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.hints p:first-child {
    padding-bottom: 0.4rem;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #a6a4a4;   
    margin-bottom: -1rem;
}
.hints p:nth-child(3) {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
}
.hint-btn {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background: none;
    width: 3rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #595656;
    background-color: #F47B13;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #F47B13;
    outline: none;
    padding-top: 0.2rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.2rem;
}
.hint-btn:hover {
    background: #c76410;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.hint-btn:active {
    background: #f2b683;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.hint-bubble {
    width: 15.6rem;
    padding: 0.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: #707070;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px black;
    padding: 0.7rem;
    transition: 0.8s;
    
    right: 28rem;
    bottom: 32.5rem;
    display: none;
}
.hint-bubble:before {
  position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0.8rem solid #707070;
    right: 7.2rem;
    top: -1.3rem;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const btnHint = document.querySelector(".hint-btn");
const hintBubble  = document.querySelector(".hint-bubble");
const hintsBox = document.querySelector(".hints");
let isOn = null;

btnHint.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (isOn) {
        hintBubble.style.display = "none";
        isOn = false;
    } else {
        hintBubble.style.display = "unset";
        isOn = true;
    }
});
```

You can also check it on codepen if you prefer: https://codepen.io/gchib00/pen/ExNrvrR

Comment: you can `opacity : 0;` instead of `display : none;`. and `position : absolute` for positioning so it would not disturb other elements on the dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transition` does not work with `display` rule. Use the rules of `opacity` and `visibility` together.

Add `visibility: hidden` and `opacity: 0`, as default, to the css, to the selector `.hint-bubble`. And delete `display: none`.

Also, pay attention to the javascript code.

```js
const btnHint = document.querySelector(".hint-btn");
const hintBubble = document.querySelector(".hint-bubble");
const hintsBox = document.querySelector(".hints");
let isOn = null;

btnHint.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (isOn) {
        hintBubble.style.visibility = "hidden";
        hintBubble.style.opacity = "0";
        isOn = false;
    } else {
        hintBubble.style.visibility = "visible";
        hintBubble.style.opacity = "1";
        isOn = true;
    }
});
```

```css
.hints {
    right: 28rem;
    bottom: 33.4rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #707070;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px black;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.hints p:first-child {
    padding-bottom: 0.4rem;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #a6a4a4;
    margin-bottom: -1rem;
}

.hints p:nth-child(3) {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.hint-btn {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    background: none;
    width: 3rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #595656;
    background-color: #f47b13;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #f47b13;
    outline: none;
    padding-top: 0.2rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.2rem;
}

.hint-btn:hover {
    background: #c76410;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.hint-btn:active {
    background: #f2b683;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.hint-bubble {
    width: 15.6rem;
    padding: 0.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: #707070;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px black;
    padding: 0.7rem;
    transition: 0.8s;

    right: 28rem;
    bottom: 32.5rem;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.hint-bubble:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0.8rem solid #707070;
    right: 7.2rem;
    top: -1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="hints">
    <p>Need help?</p>
    <br />
    <p>Click button below to get some hints!</p>
    <p>
        <button class="hint-btn">Hints</button>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="hint-bubble">I would like this div to slide out when "Hints" button is clicked
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `display` to **transition** visibility of objects,
 instead use `opacity` and `pointer-event: none` to make it not block clicks

You can also use `classList.toggle` to more easily toggle and not have to worry about the previous state.
It also allows you to put your visible styles in the stylesheet and not in the script which makes it easier to maintain

```js
const btnHint = document.querySelector(".hint-btn");
const hintBubble = document.querySelector(".hint-bubble");
const hintsBox = document.querySelector(".hints");

btnHint.addEventListener("click", () => {

  hintBubble.classList.toggle("shown")

});
```

```css
.hints {
  right: 28rem;
  bottom: 33.4rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #707070;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px black;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.hints p:first-child {
  padding-bottom: 0.4rem;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #a6a4a4;
  margin-bottom: -1rem;
}

.hints p:nth-child(3) {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.hint-btn {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background: none;
  width: 3rem;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #595656;
  background-color: #F47B13;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #F47B13;
  outline: none;
  padding-top: 0.2rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.2rem;
}

.hint-btn:hover {
  background: #c76410;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.hint-btn:active {
  background: #f2b683;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.hint-bubble {
  width: 15.6rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #707070;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px black;
  padding: 0.7rem;
  transition: 0.8s;
  right: 28rem;
  bottom: 32.5rem;
  transform: translateX(-20px);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.hint-bubble.shown {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.hint-bubble::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0.8rem solid #707070;
  right: 7.2rem;
  top: -1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="hints">
  <p>Need help?</p>
  <br />
  <p>Click button below to get some hints!</p>
  <button class="hint-btn">Hints</button>
</div>
<div class="hint-bubble">I would like this div to slide out when "Hints" button is clicked</div>
```

#### read more:

- [displaying-div-in-a-smooth-manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604703/displaying-div-in-a-smooth-manner/66604911#66604911)
- [MDN transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)