# How do you handle with two vertical scrolls on a webpage using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests

Has anyone handle two vertical scrollbars, I want to inner scrollbar will down, but the code I used only outer scroll is working. below is the code and screenshot.

[Screenshot of two Scroll Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySuj7.png)

```
//to perform Scroll on application using Selenium
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 300)", "");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scroll to an element inside a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635706/how-to-scroll-to-an-element-inside-a-div)

Comment: @cruisepandey No it's different. This scroll is not inside the element.

Comment: Can you share page url ?

Comment: Please provide a link to that page. We have nothing to do with pictures.

Comment: @HumairAli -  As per the screenshot, use `Actionschains` to move the cursor over any element in `sidebar` and then apply scrolling effect.

Comment: Thank you All. The below code works for me.

`WebElement scroll = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your Xpath"));
scroll.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);`