# How to create go to line and find text activity on textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add go to line and find text functionalities on an editor that employs textarea and a numbering div.

I have tried the following code but it is not scrolling the editor to focus on the line or text entered by the user in the prompt;

Please help me on how to implement the go to line and find text functions on the editor.

```js
const ta = document.querySelector('textarea')

function updateRowNumbering() {
  const num = ta.value.split("\n").length;
  const numbers = ta.parentNode.querySelector(".numbers");
  numbers.innerHTML = Array(num).fill("<span></span>").join("");
}

ta.value = `One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
Seven
Eight
Nine
Ten
Eleven
Kumi na Mbili
`
updateRowNumbering()


//Trying to implement go to line and find text;
const numbers = ta.parentNode.querySelector('.numbers');
const gotoLinePrompt = document.querySelector('.goto-line-prompt');
const findPrompt = document.querySelector('.find-prompt');

// Hide the prompts by default.
gotoLinePrompt.style.display = 'none';
findPrompt.style.display = 'none';

// Add event listeners to the "Go to Line" and "Find" buttons.
document.querySelector('.goto-line-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  gotoLinePrompt.style.display = 'block';
});

document.querySelector('.find-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  findPrompt.style.display = 'block';
});

// Add event listeners to the "OK" buttons in the prompts.
gotoLinePrompt.querySelector('.ok-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const lineNumber = gotoLinePrompt.querySelector('input').value;
  if (lineNumber !== null) {
    const lineHeight = ta.scrollHeight / ta.clientHeight;
    ta.scrollTop = (lineNumber - 1) * lineHeight;
    numbers.scrollTop = ta.scrollTop;
  }

  gotoLinePrompt.style.display = 'none';
});

findPrompt.querySelector('.ok-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const searchTerm = findPrompt.querySelector('input').value;
  if (searchTerm !== null) {
    const text = ta.textContent;
    const index = text.indexOf(searchTerm);
    if (index !== -1) {
      const lineNumber = Math.floor(index / ta.value.split('\n')[0].length) + 1;
      ta.scrollTop = (lineNumber - 1) * lineHeight;
      numbers.scrollTop = ta.scrollTop;
    }
  }

  findPrompt.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
body, textarea {
  font-family: Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

.editor {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3em auto;
  gap: 10px;
  line-height: 21px;
  background: rgb(40 42 58);
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.editor>* {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.numbers {
  text-align: right;
  background: #333;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.numbers span {
  counter-increment: linenumber;
}

.numbers span::before {
  content: counter(linenumber);
  display: block;
  color: #888;
}

textarea {
  line-height: 21px;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 500px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="actions">
<div class="goto-line-prompt" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Go to Line</h1>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Enter the line number to go to:" />
  <button type="button" class="ok-button">OK</button>
</div>
<div class="find-prompt" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Find</h1>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the text to find:" />
  <button type="button" class="ok-button">OK</button>
</div>
<button class="goto-line-button">Go to Line</button>
<button class="find-button">Find</button>
</div>
<div class="editor">
 <div class="numbers">
      <span></span>
   </div>
 <textarea wrap="off" onkeyup="updateRowNumbering()"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635706/how-to-scroll-to-an-element-inside-a-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.value` is NEVER going to be null so that check is useless. There is no `textContent` for a text area.

There are built in apis to scroll to an element into the view so there is no reason to reinvent the wheel.

```js
const ta = document.querySelector('textarea')

function updateRowNumbering() {
  const num = ta.value.split("\n").length;
  const numbers = ta.parentNode.querySelector(".numbers");
  numbers.innerHTML = Array(num).fill("<span></span>").join("");
}

ta.value = `One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
Seven
Eight
Nine
Ten
Eleven
Kumi na Mbili
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
foo bar
`
updateRowNumbering()


//Trying to implement go to line and find text;
const numbers = ta.parentNode.querySelector('.numbers');
const gotoLinePrompt = document.querySelector('.goto-line-prompt');
const findPrompt = document.querySelector('.find-prompt');

// Hide the prompts by default.
gotoLinePrompt.style.display = 'none';
findPrompt.style.display = 'none';

// Add event listeners to the "Go to Line" and "Find" buttons.
document.querySelector('.goto-line-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  gotoLinePrompt.style.display = 'block';
});

document.querySelector('.find-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  findPrompt.style.display = 'block';
});

function scrollToLine(lineNumber) {
  if (!lineNumber || lineNumber < 1) return;
  const nums = document.querySelectorAll(".editor > .numbers > span");
  const selectedNum = nums[lineNumber - 1];
  if (!selectedNum) return;
  selectedNum.scrollIntoView();
}

// Add event listeners to the "OK" buttons in the prompts.
gotoLinePrompt.querySelector('.ok-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const lineNumber = Number(gotoLinePrompt.querySelector('input').value.trim());
  scrollToLine(lineNumber);
  gotoLinePrompt.style.display = 'none';
});

findPrompt.querySelector('.ok-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const searchTerm = findPrompt.querySelector('input').value.trim();
  if (!searchTerm.length) return;
  const textLines = ta.value.split('\n');
  
  const lineNumber = textLines.findIndex(text => text.includes(searchTerm));
  
  if (lineNumber > -1) {
    scrollToLine(lineNumber + 1);
  }

  findPrompt.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
body,
textarea {
  font-family: Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

.editor {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3em auto;
  gap: 10px;
  line-height: 21px;
  background: rgb(40 42 58);
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.editor>* {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.numbers {
  text-align: right;
  background: #333;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.numbers span {
  counter-increment: linenumber;
}

.numbers span::before {
  content: counter(linenumber);
  display: block;
  color: #888;
}

textarea {
  line-height: 21px;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 500px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="actions">
  <div class="goto-line-prompt" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Go to Line</h1>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter the line number to go to:" />
    <button type="button" class="ok-button">OK</button>
  </div>
  <div class="find-prompt" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Find</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the text to find:" />
    <button type="button" class="ok-button">OK</button>
  </div>
  <button class="goto-line-button">Go to Line</button>
  <button class="find-button">Find</button>
</div>
<div class="editor">
  <div class="numbers">
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <textarea wrap="off" onkeyup="updateRowNumbering()"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues I can see here, but I think the core of your problem is that you're targeting the textarea to scroll when you should be targeting the editor component. You'll notice that if you set the height/min-height on `.editor` (not `.editor>*`) to something tiny like 40px, you get a double scrollbar scenario where the textarea scrolls, as well as the editor – and if you try to scroll the numbers, the entire editor scrolls, whereas when focused on the textarea, only the text scrolls.

Directionally, something like this may help:

```js
const editor = document.querySelector('.editor')
// ^ add another selector for editor
const ta = document.querySelector('textarea')
...

gotoLinePrompt.querySelector('.ok-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const lineNumber = gotoLinePrompt.querySelector('input').value;
  if (lineNumber !== null) {
    const lineHeight = 21; // I hard-coded this to test, but your math may still work
    editor.scrollTop = (lineNumber - 1) * lineHeight;
    // ^ scroll the whole editor instead
...
```

```css
.editor {
  ...
  /* Add a specific height property here to test */
  height: 70px; 
}

textarea {
  ...
  /* Add overflow: hidden here to make sure the text area doesn't scroll on its own */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

+1 also to @epascarello's answer with points on not reinventing scrolling APIs, this will help make sure things scroll correctly whichever element you end up scrolling.